# How to get the process ID of the current process in Erlang shell?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

How to get the **process ID** of the current running process while accessing the shell in Erlang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Processes**
    - The basic unit of concurrency
    - Cheap to spawn
    - Have own stack & heap - do not share memory with other processes
    - Communication is done via asynchronous message passing.
    - Example :

Erlang shell access

```
   > self().
     <0.720.0>  -- Process id
   > self() ! {hello, world}, ok.
      ok
   > self() ! {hello, world}, ok.
      ok
   > flush().        // Prints what you had done in the session
     Shell got {hello, world}   
     Shell got {hello, world}
     ok
```